# Getting errors in Codeigniter after moving application

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

```
                    if ($query1->num_rows() > 0){
                        log_message('debug', 'Cert Found');
                        $result[$i]->cert = $query1->result()[0]->door_resource_url;
                    } else {
                        log_message('debug', 'Cert Not Found');
                        $result[$i]->cert = "no";
                    }
```

This `$query1->result()[0]` is what's throwing the error but I don't see why because it worked before I moved hosting and now I can't seem to work out the issue.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I got it, I think its a difference in PHP versions that was doing it.

Comment: $result[$i]->cert = $query1->row(1)->door_resource_url;

Comment: Whenever you report that you are getting errors in an application, _please_, every time, mention what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's likely the php version of your hosting is < 5.4.0, when [function dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) was added:

> Function array dereferencing has been added, **e.g. foo()[0].**

So you can't do `$query1->result()[0]` but you need to assign it to a variable and reference it there:

```
$temp = $query1->result();
$result[$i]->cert = $temp[0]->door_resource_url;
```